# Why does this Xcode project using Metal to display camera output have so much impact on the battery, and how can I make it better?

Tags: swift, performance, camera, metal, battery

I'm using [CoreImageHelpers](https://github.com/FlexMonkey/CoreImageHelpers) as a basis of using Metal to display live filtered output through the camera. The problem is that I unexpectedly get high battery impact, when I expect Metal to perform a lot better than updating a UIImageView or even OpenGL.

**Update: Test with [my forked version](https://github.com/exactspace/CoreImageHelpers), OR**

**Before testing the original project, be sure to update a couple things:**

-In ImageView.swift, draw() must be called after commandBuffer.commit()

-Wrap DispatchQueue.main.async around connection.videoOrientation in captureOutput:

```
    DispatchQueue.main.async{
        connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation(rawValue: UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation.rawValue)!

    }
```

I'm testing on an iPhone 6s Plus, and the one CICMYKHalftone effect ramps the battery impact to high when viewing in the Debug Navigator.

I thought using this Metal view would drastically help performance, but it does not seem to, even when running at a lower frame rate of 25-30 fps.

Is there anything vital missing that would make battery usage better like other live camera effects apps?

**Updates**:

Another performance update I added is the MTKView's setting for preferredFramesPerSecond, which I set to 30, since it will by default call up to 60 times a second. I combine this with a lower device frame rate to achieve better performance and less battery impact.

Comment: Why would you expect Metal to be faster than updating a UIImageView or using OpenGL? The workload on the CPU and GPU is the same for all of these. Metal has less overhead than OpenGL but the computational capacity and memory bandwidth of the GPU doesn't magically change if you use Metal. (If Metal does much worse than a UIImageView or OpenGL, then something is going wrong, of course.)

Comment: Since I’m filtering images with CIFilters, it is necessary to create a CIImage right after I get an image from the pixel buffer. Implementing Metal allows me to render an image faster onto the view without first converting to a CGImage. Metal is more optimized than OpenGL and I have compared the impact. It’s not really about performance, and more about battery impact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, since you're driving the drawing manually (by invoking `draw()`), you should set the view's `isPaused` property to true. If you don't do that, the view is drawing itself both when you call that and on an internal timer.

Second, the relationship between `renderImage()` and `draw()` is inverted. The `image` `didSet` observer should not call `renderImage()`. It should call `draw()`. You should have an override of `draw(_ rect: CGRect)` that does the work of `renderImage()` (minus the call to `draw()`). (You can either have `draw(_ rect: CGRect)` call `renderImage()` or you can simply rename `renderImage()` to `draw(_ rect: CGRect)`.)

Depending on your exact needs, you could also set `enableSetNeedsDisplay` to true and change the `image` `didSet` to call `setNeedsDisplay()` instead of `draw()`. That will have a bit more latency but will avoid attempts to draw too often.

Comment: Thanks Ken - I think I understand everything except for the first suggestion. Do you mean I should set MetalImageView's paused property to true? I don't see that property.

Comment: `paused` is a property of `MTKView`. `MetalImageView` inherits it.

Comment: I see isPaused and pause()

Comment: Sorry, `isPaused`. It's called `paused` in Objective-C.

Comment: Thanks, it seems to knock off a small amount of battery impact, but it is still well into the "high" range. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Have you read [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/EnergyGuide-iOS/MonitorEnergyWithXcode.html) and [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/EnergyGuide-iOS/MonitorEnergyWithInstruments.html)?

Comment: The second one, yes. My computer isn't fast enough to handle profiling with Instruments unfortunately, but recently I found out that I can record the performance from the phone itself, then import it into Instruments, so that may be something.

Comment: I was able to run the CoreImageHelpers project by itself with the Time Profiler, and what I determined is that creating the CIImage with the cvPixelBuffer takes the longest. (This is without filters). I'm not sure how to get around that. Also the ciContext.render function is quite hefty.

Comment: So you've throttled how often the view displays. How often is AVCapture delivering you a frame? It may be doing so more often than needed. Also, in `CameraCaptureHelper.captureOutput`, you're misusing dispatch. First, only shunt things that actually need to be done on the main thread to the main queue. Querying `UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation` may, setting `connection.videoOrientation` doesn't. Further, that block has to be synchronous, not async. Calling `newCameraImage` may be main-thread only, but creating the `CIImage` isn't.

Comment: Are you sure about the dispatch on the CIImage? Setting the image calls setNeedsDisplay which invokes draw and calls render on the CIContext. Without any dispatch queue, I get lots of errors in the console and the app slows way down. Maybe you meant that I should have some of it running on the main thread, but not when rendering the image? Luckily on my real app I don't do anything with the camera orientation in captureOutput. I do however, apply a the filter on the image on a synchronous background thread which I'm unsure if it has any positive effect.

Comment: I believe you should create the `CIImage` from the pixel buffer on the thread where `captureOutput` is called, but then call `newCameraImage` on the main thread. So, you would split what is currently one statement into two.

Comment: I made that change on the CoreImageHelpers project. Looks to be about the same, but still I believe that would be the more appropriate way of doing it.

Comment: I don't know if this is supported (docs suggest it isn't), but you can try setting `videoOutput.videoSettings` to a dictionary mapping `kCVPixelBufferMetalCompatibilityKey` to true.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but curiously I get no video output when I set that.

Comment: It looks like that key depends on using CVMetalTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage, which I have also tried, but gives me rows of black and white video. Still, setting that key gives me no video output, but from the docs, it says I'd need to create buffers, which I don't know enough about: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corevideo/1456754-cvmetaltexturecachecreatetexture?language=objc